# MS Management Studio will not open stored procs node

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

When I attempt to expand the stored procedures tab in Management Studio I am getting the following error and no stored procedures are displayed. I've tried re-running all stored procedure scripts (which works without errors) and refreshing the tab, but I still get the following error:

===================================

Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=601&LinkId=20476

---

Server Name: precysesql,1433
Error Number: 601
Severity: 12
State: 3
Line Number: 9

---

Program Location:

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.ReadInternal()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.Read()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItemWithQuery(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, String urnQuery, Boolean registerBuilder, Boolean registerBuiltItems)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItem(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NonContextFilterNavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 targetList, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.GetChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are still on RTM; have you considered applying SP1 and CU4 to your server and client?  Not that that will *definitely* fix the issue, but it could be a start.  Also try recycling the SQL Server service.  There seems to be some activity going on that is affecting access to catalog views.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you mean you installed SP1 on the server, on the client, and restarted SQL Server, and *still* you cannot expand the stored procedures node?  Do all other nodes expand gracefully?  Does this only happen in one database?  If so, what does DBCC OPENTRAN yield?